# How to set the "api_key" value in Travis CI

Tags: java, spring, heroku, continuous-integration, travis-ci

I am deploying a Spring app to Heroku via Travis CI. However, despite setting up my travis file different ways, I can't seem to resolve the following issues, the primary one being the missing api key.

[image]

Below is several examples of format attempts I have tried in different order, none of which have worked.

```
api-key: "secure api key"

api_key:
  secure: "secure api key"

app: friend-status-dev
env:
  global:
  - secure: "secure api key"
jdk:
- oraclejdk8
deploy:
  provider: heroku
```

Despite all of this, and event setting env vars via the Travis UI, it does not seem to want to find the "api_key" field in my .travis.yml file. I know for a fact that it can at the least find my .travis file, as it is using the jdk actively.

Comment: Have you tried putting `api_key` under `deploy` (alongside `provider`)? Where are you getting the api_key value you from?

Comment: @codefinger I see now. Thank you for pointing out that oversight, adding it under deploy did the trick.

Comment: Where does one obtain a travis API key in the first place?

Comment: @mareoraft For Travis to work, you just need to give it permission to your Github repo that you want to integrate it with, along with .travis.yml for any configurations. In this case the api key isn't a "travis api key" per say, but a api key from Heroku that allows Travis to deploy to the dev environment I had on Heroku

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `deploy` section should look like this:

```
deploy:
  provider: heroku
  api_key: "secure api key"
```